# rtk-gps faster (60Hz) and cheaper?

Tags: mobile-robot

The below rtk-gps measures position to about 1.5inches
for $1500 and an update rate of 5Hz on gps, and it measures
12.6mm x 4.6mm so that it would easily fit inside of
a 20mm-diameter tube-shaped rocket-robot.

https://inertialsense.com/product/ins/
https://inertialsense.com/data-sheet/

Do people sell cheaper ones that are faster, say 60Hz instead of 5Hz,
but still meet the above or similar gps-accuracy and still fit inside
a 20mm-diameter tube?  Something in the vicinity of $200-ish or less.

I apologize in advance if this is a "shopping question".
I don't have 'privilege' to post in the 'chat-section'.

Comment: the 1.5" accuracy is probably not based on GPS data alone

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](https://drotek.com/tiny-rtk-u-blox-neo-m8p/)? It's pretty close to the dimensions you are searching for 23.5x24.5